# Rally combobox doesn't work on click

Tags: javascript, html, sdk, rally

I want to create combobox listing all the PortfolioItem/Feature filtered by Name. Here is my code

```
        Ext.define('Rally.Dashboard', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            launch: function () {
                if (this.down('#features')) {
                    this.down('#features').destroy();
                }

                var features = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox', {
                    itemId: 'features',
                    allowNoEntry: false,
                    storeConfig: {
                        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
                        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ObjectID', 'UserStories'],
                        autoSelect: true,
                        pageSize: 100,
                        autoLoad: true,
                        filters: [this._getFilter()]
                    },
                    fieldLabel: 'Select Feature',
                    listeners: {
                        ready: function (combobox) {
                            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                                this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                            }
                        },
                        select: function (combobox) {
                            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                                this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
                            }

                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
                this.add(features);

            },
            _onFeatureSelected: function (feature) {

                console.log('feature', feature.get('Name'));


            },//_onFeatureSelected

            _getFilter: function ()
            {
                return {
                    property: 'Name',
                    operator: 'Contains',
                    value: 'Feature'
                }
            }

        });
        Rally.launchApp('Rally.Dashboard', {
            name: 'example'
        });
```

When dashboard loads for first time, everything works correctly. But when i click the combobox, the combobox will be cleaned up, and in the log, it shows response error

"QueryResult": {"Errors": ["Could not parse: Could not find attribute \"_refObjectName\" on type PortfolioItems in the query segment \"_refObjectName\""], "TotalResultCount": 0, "StartIndex": 0, "PageSize": 0, "Results": []}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the combobox.  Unfortunately this component has had a rough life due to many, many varied usages across the product and a couple incompatible ExtJS upgrades over time.

There's a really nice Artifact Search combobox that I'd recommend using instead, as I think it handles a bunch of the weirdness (including typeahead search) for you:

```
 var features = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ArtifactSearchComboBox', {
     itemId: 'features',
     allowNoEntry: false,
     storeConfig: {
         models: ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
         fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ObjectID', 'UserStories'],
         pageSize: 100,
         autoLoad: true // or false if you want to wait to load until click
     },
     fieldLabel: 'Select Feature',
     listeners: {
         ready: function (combobox) {
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
         },
         select: function (combobox) {
             if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                 this._onFeatureSelected(combobox.getRecord());
             }
         },
         scope: this
     }
});
```